# Skew left and right side border of an element in CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-1 lft-rht">
      <p>TO</p>
      <p class="text-bottom">IDR</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-7">
      <div class="spcl">
          <p>By First <br> Career</p>
          <p class="bordr px-5 text center">Here i need the curved border edges</p>
      </div>
      <p class="text-bottom">6E</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 lft-rht">
      <p>TO</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
      <p>By</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1 lft-rht">
      <p>To</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-1">
       <p>By</p>
   </div>
</div
```

```
/*CSS Part*/

.bordr {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
.lft-rht{
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-right:1px solid black;
      }
.spcl {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
p.text-bottom {
             align-items: flex-end;
             margin-bottom: 0px;
          }
```

I  want to rotate the border (Left and Right side) of the rows of the table as mention in reference image. I have tried to lot more but not succeed. I just want the CSS part of design. Please help me to find the solution. Thank in advance.

I need CSS part of the mention design

[image]

This format i should need as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use before and after pseudo-elements.

```css
#grey {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#grey:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 50px solid #fff;
  width: 0px;
}

#grey:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 50px solid #fff;
  border-top: 50px solid #ccc;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grey"> 
  content
</div>
```

Comment: Its not working, Sir..   I need with the border

Comment: can please show me using the border not background color

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it is not possible in css to do this with the borders of a container. The only solutions I see are the one I gave via pseudo elements or another solution via svg. In pure CSS, via the borders, you can simply round the corners of your container until you get a circle